# PHP: get_headers empty result

Tags: php, apache, header, get, http-headers

I have a script that check if the file exist on another server with `get_headers`. I've two servers on one server it works, on the other I get an empty response from `get_headers`.

my code:

```
$myurl='http://stackoverflow.com/';
$header = get_headers($myurl);
print_r($header);
```

php version

```
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug  6 2012 14:18:06) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

solution:

No sure what it was, my apache log was full of those errors 
`failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: System error`

after a reboot it all went away and `get_headers` is working now.

Comment: looks like phpwtf, maybe use curl instead?

Comment: I would use curl as well so that you can execute a HEAD request, or use `stream_context_set_default()` to make HTTP requests use HEAD instead.  No reason to do this with a full GET if you are only interested in headers.

Answer (score 0):

Check if allow_url_fopen is on.

> php --info | grep allow_url_fopen

Comment: php --info | grep allow_url_fopen
allow_url_fopen => On => On